# Resposive website image size issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

Hello I am developing responsive website for video listing site.

Here I am issue when different size image comes in listing. I am attaching screenshot of issue.

[image: CSS image issue]

Most of image in listing have same height and width but for some items image height varies so my UI gets distorted. As I am making responsive website so I cannot fix image height or width.

I am using width:100% and height:auto for image. As I need a way so if someone increase or decrease browser size, item image size gets increase or decrease respectively.

So is there any way to resolve that issue?